# Using MSpec runner in Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, resharper, mspec

I'm a big fan of MSpec so naturally I wanted to use is right away with VS2010 as well. I have the MSpec runner defined as an external tool in Visual Studio to be able to have it always visible as a toolbar item.

Anyway, whenever I try to use the MSpec runner (mspec.exe) with a .NET 4.0 solution I get the following error:

> `Could not load file or assembly 
>   'file:///C:\Users\[SOMEUSER]\[SOME_FOLDERS]\bin\Debug\[PROJECT].Specs.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.`

I can still run my specs with the Resharper 5 runner so it's no big drama, but I bothers me to no end :þ

Do you guys have any idea what the problem could be? Is there any solution other than recompiling the whole Mspec source code as a .NET 4.0 solution, which I really, really don't want to do?

Thanks in advance.
Sergi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use my `net4` branch which contains a version of MSpec that is compatible with .NET 4.0. We're working on integrating these changes into MSpec's master.

<strike>http://github.com/agross/machine.specifications/tree/net4</strike>

Update: Current builds are available on [Codebetter's TeamCity server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project27) (Choose guest login)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for an answer either from you or Aaron Jensen ;)

Comment: :) We also have a .NET 4.0 build available on http://teamcity.codebetter.com now.

Comment: Should this URL be updated? the link is broken - perhaps https://github.com/agross/machine.specifications ?

Comment: Hi Alexander - I am having trouble finding the .NET 4 build on the TeamCity server.  Is it not here? http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt44&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv

Comment: Brian, the .NET 4 build is included in the normal build. Use mspec-clr4.exe to run specs compiled against .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by running the tests with the `mspec-clr4.exe` instead.